# Why +1 in realloc for string in C? If it's for null terminator, then how does strlen() measures len of the str if there's no null byte at the end?

Tags: c, memory, realloc, strlen

This code is from a problem in HackerRank (Q: [Printing Tokens](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/printing-tokens-/problem) in C).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));  // Allocate for string
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s)+1);   // Here's my doubt

    // Solution
    
    return 0;
}
```

Forget about the question, look at the following iteration-

```
s = realloc( s, strlen(s)+1 );   // +1
```

This line of code reallocates the memory of the string 's' according to the length of the string 's', It also increases the length for a null terminator '\0'. But strlen() only measures until it reaches '\0', but there's no '\0' in 's' as we're adding a byte for '\0'. How can we assume it will measure the perfect length of string 's'? If it measures the perfect length of 's' then there must be a null terminator at the end so why add 1 again?

Someone explain this, there's no null terminator '\0' so we add a byte for it.

Or Am I completely wrong about this?

Comment: Of course, there is a nul-terminator in the string. `scanf` puts it there after the last input character. Otherwise it would not be a string in C at all. That `realloc` call can only be used to reduce the size of the buffer. It cannot increase it that way.

Comment: If there's no null-terminator, it's not a null-terminated string. And you can't pass it to any function expecting a null-terminated string. All those functions will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, this is some pretty bad code in terms of execution speed. It would be better without the realloc.

Comment: OT: Why does the HackerRank _starter_ code use `#include <math.h>` for this text processing challenge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Someone explain this, there's no null terminator '\0' so we add a byte for it.

You are misinterpreting what happens here.

`scanf` is used to read a string into the memory pointed to by `s`.
In C, a string is a nul-terminated sequence of characters. That means, it is responsibility of `scanf` to place the 0 byte there after the last character from the input.

If that weren't the case, you would not be allowed to pass `s` to `strlen` at all because it expects a nul-terminated string.

In `realloc` the `+1` is not added to add a 0 byte. It is added to keep the memory of that byte. You start with a large buffer and resize to the length you need. For this, you must add 1 to prevent the last byte from being freed during `realloc`.

So, the assumption that there would not be a nul-terminator, is wrong. It is there all the time and shall still be there after reducing the buffer size.